# How to take a snapshot of video control?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have an `mx:Video` object that plays live streaming video. How can I take a snapshot of that video?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your VideoDisplay object is called "v":

```
<mx:VideoDisplay id="v" source="..." ... />
```

Then you can draw the contents onto a Bitmap object like so:

```
var bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(v.width, v.height);
bd.draw(v);

var b:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bd);
```

Now the Bitmap object has a snapshot of the video.